# Is there a way to prevent Model.find({}) from returning results in an infinite loop?

Tags: express, mern

I am creating a MERN application. In the controller, I have used the mongoose find({}) to list the blogs. But, the query has returned the results in an infinite loop.

I have tried this, and I am expecting how to stop the looping.

```
async function rowCount(rows){
         totalBlogs=rows;             
         totalPages=Math.ceil(totalBlogs/pageNo);             
         offset=(pageNo-1)*pageLimit; 
         await blogModel.find({}).skip(offset).limit(pageLimit).sort({blogDate:-1})
         .then(result=>{
                           res.json({    
                                      "flag":"success",
                                       "data":result,
                                       "totalPages":totalPages,
                                       "totalBlogs":totalBlogs
                                });  

                                console.log(result);
                                                                                                                                                                   

        })
        .catch(error=>{   
                           res.json({
                                       "flag":"error",
                                       "data":[],
                                       "totalPages":"0",
                                       "totalBlogs":"0"
                                }); 

         }); 

   }
```